# Weird wireless connection issue

Tags: wireless

I am currently having a weird internet connection problem.

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 on a dual boot using Gnome Classic interface and using a wireless usb adapter.

The issue I am having is that my internet connection keeps dropping and then 5 seconds later, it reconnects and only stays connected for 10 to 15 seconds, before dropping again.

- I have tried checking the additional drivers but it does not list my usb adapter but drivers for my Nvidia Geforce 640 graphics card.
- I checked in Terminal and my system does list the adapter but there is no GUI for it. The adapter is the MediaLink Wireless-N USB Adapter(Model # MWN-USB150N).
- I checked MediaLink's website and they do have a Linux driver but after downloading it and reading the instructions it was way too technical and beyond my skills to try to install it since I am new to Linux.
- I have spent hours reading forums and trying the desktop help to try to solve this.

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

```
lz@lz-MS-7845:~$ sudo lsmod
[sudo] password for lz: 
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   17830  2 
rfcomm                 38139  0 
bluetooth             158447  10 bnep,rfcomm
parport_pc             32114  0 
ppdev                  12849  0 
arc4                   12473  2 
rt2800usb              22373  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31775  1 
rt2800lib              53298  1 rt2800usb
crc_ccitt              12627  1 rt2800lib
snd_hda_codec_realtek   174313  1 
rt2x00usb              20099  1 rt2800usb
rt2x00lib              48875  3 rt2800usb,rt2800lib,rt2x00usb
snd_hda_intel          32719  5 
mac80211              436493  3 rt2800lib,rt2x00usb,rt2x00lib
snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
nvidia               8502822  39 
cfg80211              178877  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
snd_pcm                80916  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                51592  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
mxm_wmi                12893  0 
snd                    62218  20 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
mac_hid                13077  0 
soundcore              14635  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
serio_raw              13027  0 
video                  19115  0 
wmi                    18744  1 mxm_wmi
lp                     17455  0 
parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
usbhid                 41937  0 
hid                    77428  1 usbhid
```

dmesg command:
[  181.798032] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
[  181.798033] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
[  181.798035] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
[  181.798036] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
[  181.798037] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: ERROR no room on ep ring
and continues on and on with same error.

lsusb command:
lz@lz-MS-7845:~$ sudo lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter

Comment: The trick to Googling wifi related issues is to go by the name of the wireless chipset, rather than the manufacturer of the wifi card. Most chipsets are used in more than one model of wifi card. For example, yours uses the `rt2870sta` chipset.

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from the terminal command: lsusb

Comment: I would recommend filing a kernel bug. Often times these things go unnoticed by developers and then there is an unpredictable cycle of "new kernel release", "still not fixed", "old solution doesn't work", "new solution found", "repeat". : https://bugzilla.kernel.org/ You will need to provide more information than this, for example `dmesg` output and `lsusb` output.

Answer (score 0):

[One person](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1523341) got this to work by removing the rt2800usb module and waiting a minute or so:

```
sudo modprobe -r rt2800usb
```

Comment: lz@lz-MS-7845:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 148f:3070 Ralink Technology, Corp. RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter

Comment: I meant that the given command (which was `sudo rmmod rt2800usb`) should be run in the terminal, not `lsusb`. Please edit your Question to include this info as @chili555 suggested.

Comment: lz@lz-MS-7845:~$ sudo rmmod rt2800usb
ERROR: Module rt2800usb does not exist in /proc/modules
lz@lz-MS-7845:~$

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `lsmod`?

Comment: I edited the command; try it as it is now...

Comment: lz@lz-MS-7845:~$ sudo modprobe -r rt2800usb
lz@lz-MS-7845:~$ 
                                                                   Nothing happened.

Comment: lz@lz-MS-7845:~$ sudo modprobe -r rt2800usb
lz@lz-MS-7845:~$ 
Nothing happened.

Comment: Well no output means the command did its job... did it solve the issue?

Comment: No. After trying the command I went into network tools and the loopback was on and not the wlan so I selected the wlan. At first it seemed to be working but recently I just was trying to get online and the connection dropped and it could'nt seem to connect. It is strange that in network tools the wlan is never on by default or the fact that it will never stay on wlan but on loopback whenever I exit and reenter network tools.